# How can I buy something in German if I live in the U.S.?

Tags: itunes, audio, language

I want to buy the German dubbed version of South Park.  How can I do this?  I changed my region to Germany and found what I want to purchase.  I even previewed the episode and sure enough the audio-language-dub is in German.  iTunes won't let me buy this though because it's not available in my region.

So I bought the English-U.S. version with hopes I could change the audio settings, which I read how to do here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202641 (click "On Mac or PC").  I don't get all those options though.  I know the exact episode I purchased is available in German, since I previewed it in the German store, but I don't have these options.

What can I do to get this in German?

Answer (score 1):

I live in the Netherlands and I am well able to buy from the German Store. My (original) iTunes Account is German, so there is no issue when I am in the German Store and logged in with the German Account.

It also works the other way around. Sometimes I want to buy things from the dutch Store. I have a second Account for this. When I switch the store, I also logout and login with the NL Account again.

The only catch: You need a valid payment method for each country. Otherwise I experienced no problem having a second account, nor location-based restrictions.

(Disclaimer: I only tested this with Apps, which were not available in all regions.)

Answer (score 0):

It is up to the distributor of the video to choose which languages (dubs or subtitles) are installed for which market. If there are no audio settings or if German is not listed then it is not available on the US copy you have purchased.

Regarding purchasing from a foreign iTunes store, unfortunately you cannot, see [Buy from foreign iTunes stores](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3737921?start=0&tstart=0).